# How to connect Micromax 3G modem in Ubuntu

Tags: connection, usb-modem, 3g

Whenever I want to connect my Micromax 3G modem, ubuntu doesn't connect it. But I can access my inserted memory card from modem.

I'm posting an image in which I use `lsusb` command to see the information about my modem (dark white colored is my modem detailed):

[image]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: If i have an option to post an image during ask a question then why did you say "Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use"

Comment: You *have* the option doesn't mean you *should* add screenshots willy-nilly. Screenshots have their uses, but showing command-line output is not one. Refer to [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals) for five solid reasons against such this practice.